# Are these Red Army uniforms authentic?

Tags: military, russia, uniform

This image attributes all three uniforms to the Red Army of 1918-1922. I wonder whether the proposed time frame and/or details authentic. For me the first one looks like it was taken from the 1940s and the other two look like they were taken from 19th century.

[image]

Comment: Could you cite the graphic?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, these are authentic *cadette uniforms*. But note that 1 is "standard", while 2 and 3 are "parade" variants.

**No 1.** is a kind of standard infantry uniform which had a little changes from WW1 to WW2. The most controversial part is, probably, a side cap, as you see it usually only in WW2 chronicles. It was adopted as a part of Red Army infantry uniform only in 1935. Yet especially for the cadettes, the side caps were approved much earlier.

[image: Cadettes-artillerists, 1st Cavalry Army, 1920]
<sup>"The Red Сadettes-artillerists of First Cavalry Army, 1920"

From Alexander Deryabin ["The Civil War in Russia, 1917-1922. The Red Army"](http://www.e-reading.club/book.php?book=18923)</sup>

---

Another points to watch in the first picture are Mosin-Nagant rifle which dates back to 1891 (but was still in use in WW2), and *скатка* (i.e. rolled overcoat). Both show that this soldier, for sure, is an infantryman. Unfortunately, that also means that we can't see what his overcoat looks like.

**No 2.** is a parade uniform of artillerists. Look at the [shako](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shako), it was a part of dress uniform only. Except the red stars, it was borrowed from Tsarist army too. The inscription mentions "The chief of 2nd Petrograd Soviet artillery courses 1918-1922", although this name was in use only in 1920-1921. This is the same as [Mikhailovskaya Military Artillery Academy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F) which was founded in 1701 by Peter I and exists until nowadays. Here is a picture of its cadettes parading in 1918 (btw. it makes obvious why the artillerists had sabers and spurs ;-)):

[image: kursanty 1918]
<sup>"The cadettes on parade, 1918" From [Alumni club of Kolomenskoye (Mikhaylovskoye) Artillery School](http://www.kau.su/ru/)</sup>

---

The chief of the Academy in 1919-1923 was General [S.G. Petrovich](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87,_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). The insignia on the sleeve - three red squares - shows the rank of *Комбат* (i.e. Batallion Commander, close to Major or Lieutenant Colonel), since at that time there were no "standard" officer ranks in the RKKA (and even the word *officer* was replaced by *commander*). But I'm not sure, if former tsarist army General Petrovich actually had the rank of *Комбат* in RKKA around 1920.

**No 3.** is a parade cavalry uniform (actually, [Uhlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhlan) dress uniform). The inscription mentions "1st Tver commander courses". These courses were based on [Tver cavalry junker school](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5), and the uniform remained the same. Here is a photo dated 1914 from Wiki:

[image: The Tver cavalry school. Sword belts-cadets Petrov Feodor.]
<sup>"The Tver cavalry school. Sword belts-cadets Petrov Feodor. 1914"  [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%A2%D0%9A%D0%A3_8.jpg)</sup>

---

BTW. This school still works too: [Zhukov Air and Space Defense Academy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%93._%D0%9A._%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: It is called side cap/flight cap, not forage cap in English.

Comment: @Anixx OK, let it be a side cap.

Answer (score 7):

Some more pictures:

[image]

No, it is not from WWII. It's from 1920, Petrograd.

[image]

You can see the five-pointed star.

[image]

Artillery man with 5-pointed star

[image]

Cavalry men.

Red hussars:

[image]
[image]

Artillery men with 5-pointed stars:

[image]